# Why would a star move a node from closed list to open list?

Tags: algorithm

I checked the pseudo-code.

I just can't understand why a star moves a node existing in closed list to open list after updating existing node. Uniformed Cost Search only updates open list and doesn't care about closed list. I think they are similar.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :). It's better if you can formulate a clear question without reference to external resources.. the external link can and will decay. Don't just copy-paste the external doc though... try to condense the exact problem you're having down into a small amount of text that can be understood independently (and doesn't violate Stanford's copyright).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this question. I checked the textbook. A* should be identical to UCS except it estimates cost to the goal. Anyway, I will just believe those  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to move a node from CLOSED to OPEN if you are using an inconsistent heuristic.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, the algorithm is concerned with finding path costs.  If a node in CLOSED is found linked to in OPEN, this means the algorithm has found a new path to it.  This may mean that the path cost for this node has changed (if the new path has a lower cost than any path to this node yet seen), so it must be reexamined.